# Exporting data from Ada application with websocket

Tags: websocket, client-side, ada

I'm developing a scholar project where I have a core written in *Ada* language that generates data information.
As requested by the project, I need to send all the new produced information, with a certain period, to a remote webserver via websocket.

In javascript language is really easy to connect to a web socket:

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/socketserver", "protocolOne");
```

I would be able to execute a similar command in Ada, is it possible?

---

May be possible to workaround the problem calling an html page (with GET parameters) containing javascript code so that this page manages the websocket with remote webserver?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-29/ AWS is not just for web servers and may have what you need, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I can't find the informations I need. I would like to implement a PUSH model from Ada to Node.js for this reason I'm going to create an AWS server where Node.js server creates a websocket and AWS responds on creation

Comment: I think you need to investigate the capabilities that are available to you and devise a solution that effectively employs those capabilities. Versus defining a specific solution ahead of time and trying to force fit a toolkit into implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

For those still looking for this answer; AWS now supports websockets...

https://docs.adacore.com/aws-docs/aws/high_level_services.html#websockets

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Both AWS and Black has supports websockets.  AWS is the most mature of the two, so I suggest that you use that.

Comment: Thanks but I already have implemented an AWS solution like I shown in mine comment: "Thanks for your comment but I can't find the informations I need. I would like to implement a PUSH model from Ada to Node.js for this reason I'm going to create an AWS server where Node.js server creates a websocket and AWS responds on creation(on message)"